# Android RecyclerViewAdapter SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement like/dislike button inside my `RecyclerView.Adapter`, using `SharedPreferences` to store the value for each position.

```
SharedPreferences pref = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(ISLL, 0); // 0 - for private mode
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
boolean alreadyLiked = pref.getBoolean(String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()),false);
```

and inside `onClickListener` I do as follow:

```
alreadyLiked = !alreadyLiked;
editor
  .putBoolean(String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), alreadyLiked)
  .commit();
```

my changes are effective on foreground mode, but when I restart the app, changes seem to be revoked.

Comment: Where are you calling `putBoolean` in your code?

Comment: inside my `item.setOnClickListener`

Comment: Could you post please code of adapter?

Comment: can you have a code please

Comment: Code describing the issue has been submitted, you could ask where you call this how did you do this, then i would add more code.